# Solr Dynamic filter

Tags: solr4

I have electronics documents associated with metadata that I indexed into Solr. I also have a web application which allows users to login and perform searches. But then, I would like to apply dynamic access rights on documents. Let me explain. Basically for us, a document has:

- one type (Contract, CV, birth certificate, ...) about 250 unique types.
- one person concerned, about 10 000 unique persons.
- one effective date.
- one content: the electronic document

Some users should (or shouldn't) have access to some documents according to who they are in our organization. For example, user 'x' can see the CV of user 'y' from date #1 to date #2. There thousands of combinations and in fact it's more complex than just these three parameters. So I developed an application based on a rules engine which computes the access rights giving a user and a document. The rules might change quite often and the facts are constantly changing.

At this time, it works to filter the results that Solr returns on my client web application. However, by filtering after searching I lost many features provided by Solr, facets, paging, ... I am looking for a way to call my rules engine (web service) to filter results before calling other Solr components (especially facets).